# In batch file, does for loop variable (i.e. %%i) belongs to environment variable? How can we REASSIGN a value to %%i?

Tags: batch-file

I tried the following code, while the echo output was the same, namely 1. Is there any way to assign another value to a for-loop variable?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do (
echo %%i
set %%i=5
echo %%i
)
pause
```

Comment: The loop variable isn't yours to assign to; it belongs to the loop. IOW, you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just assign `%%i` to some other variable that you create and manipulate it that way (although whatever variable you create is going to be called with `!variable!` instead of `%variable%`.)

Comment: I'm suspecting this is an XY problem. It might be better if you instead explain what you're actually trying to accomplish, and ask a question about doing it.

Comment: `%%I` and `%1` are NOT environmental variables. So they can't be treated as one. `%var%` in an environmental variable.

Comment: The answer is no. Don't do this. What's your possible use case? I'd be surprised if you genuinely need to do this.

Comment: Now I have a txt file contains the creating time (i.e. 18:06 18:09 19:30...) of a bunch of files. I want to get the delta time between the first file and any other file. But 08 and 09 are not a right way to do arithmetic operation, so I need to identify and delete the first zero.@Ken White

Comment: Yeah that's true, but you cannot assign a 08 or 09 to a variable, otherwise it will throw an error to you.@ SomethingDark

Comment: @David - batch treats all numbers like strings unless you're using `set /a`; you can absolutely set a variable to 08 or 09. You get around it by saying `set /a var=1%variable%-100`

Comment: It's a little bit tricky to notice that 2 numbers can also be concatenated by simply putting them together, just as strings.  Thanks @SomethingDark

Answer (score 0):

The comments below the question already explained that the operation you are trying to achieve is fundamentally wrong.

However, I want to use a different point of view and just answer this question: "How can we REASSIGN a value to %%i?". The answer is very simple: in the same way we assign the value to the first %%i, that is, via another `for` command. This answer is obvious: if you use a `for` command to assign the value to the first %%i, why you try to use a *different command* to reassign its value?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,1) do (
echo %%i
for %%i in (5) do echo %%i
)
```

Comment: well, that just echoes `5`, but does not really reassign `%%i`. Put another `echo %%i` below the second `for`.

Comment: @Stephan: Of course that the value of `%%i` is _reassigned_; otherwise the second `echo %%i` would show a `1` instead of a `5`! Do you want to put another `echo %%i` below the second `for` and show the reassigned value? Simple: enclose it between parentheses that belong to second `for`... (Of course I understand what you mean, but the point is that the OP understand what he tried to mean in first place.  **`;-)`**  I invite you to continue this discussion, so others may review both points of view)

Comment: ok, challenge accepted `;)`. What you basically do, is something like `set var=hello`, `setlocal`, `set var=world`, `endlocal`. You create a local copy, that is not valid in the original context. A real reassignment would influence the original variable, so the following would have to work (i.e. exit the loop): `for /l %%a in (1,0,2) do (set %%a=2)` (`set %%a=...` ?! Wth?). Another `for` doesn't help: `for /l %%a in (1,0,2) do (for %%a in (2) do set %%a=%%a)`. The inner `%%a` is completely independent of the outer one, so it's technically another variable, not a reassignment.

Comment: @Stephan: Well, this is precisely the core point of this topic: the usage of the "REASSIGN" word! If the OP would asked: _"How can we CHANGE the value of `%%i`?"_ the answer would just be: "You can't". However, _reassign a value to `%%i`_ means "assign a new value to `%%i`"! The OP didn't defined if the reassigned `%%i` must be _the same_ previous `%%i` nor the number of lines (scope) where the reassigned value should exist; he just described the problem as _"the echo output was the same, namely 1"_. My answer is a valid solution to this problem because it first show a `1` and then a `5`!

Comment: @Aacini Nice discussion. Well, I don't see the difference between "REASSIGN" and "CHANGE". Semantically, both of them are an operation that uses another value to replace the former value. Anyway, thanks for pointing out this potential confused expression. A brief answer to my original question could be: %%i is looping index rather than an environment variable, so it can not be modified by users once the loop starts. Am I right?

Comment: `both of them are an operation that uses another value to replace the former value` - completely my point of view. If it isn't "the same previous `%%i`", then it's not a **re**assignment, but merely a new variable with accidentally the same name, but no influence to the original variable. It's like in some programming language where you can happily have global and local variables with the same name (but only can use one of them, according to the respective context). @David yes, you are completely right (according to my point of view `;)`)

Comment: Finally, I agree (more or less) **`:/`**. Two points: in modern programming languages, "REASSIGN a variable" means create a _new instance_ of the variable, that is, _assign (allocate) new memory_ for it; this mechanism is called [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). In Batch, this can be done on variables via `setlocal` command (as @Stephan mentioned) or on looping indices nesting `for` commands (as in my code). However, there is a second point here...

Comment: Although the answer to your last question is "Yes", I invite you to _assume_ that you can change the `%%i` looping index and then use such feature to **solve a certain problem**. Please, modify the question and add an explanation of such a problem and the code; after that, we may give you a valid equivalent code (as @SomethingDark and @KenWhite indicated). If you don't show us the purpose of your question, then this entire topic just makes no sense... **`:-(`**